# Inkscape: Copy Pasting PNG results in Black background for transparent areas

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape, If I copy an Image from internet with a transparent background and paste it into Inkscape Canvas the portions where there is transparent turns out to be black.

But if I download the image and then import the image into inkscape from the file system it works great.

I there a way through which the pasted image can retain its transparency.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The  OS I am using is Windows 10

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it work correctly with Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Oh, and: how do you copy? Drag+Drop? Ctrl+C? etc.

Comment: I use copy image option which you get when you right click on a image inside browser. You can search any png image in the browser, right click and click on copy image option.

Comment: I am using chrome browser.

Comment: Inkscape seems to have trouble with clipboard handling. You should raise a bug if there isn't one already. I know there are still problems on macOS from 2009 which looks like will be fixed soon :)